# Is there an ejs equivalent for css?

Tags: css, node.js

I am currently developing a website using node.js and express. I am using EJS as view engine. I want to be able to inject variables into my CSS, in a way that works similar to EJS.
(For those that are not familiar with EJS: I'm quite sure it works similar to the way you inject variables from the backend into HTML in PHP)
My CSS needs to be in a seperate file (not inline). This process also needs to run on the backend.
Is there any module I can use to do this in node.js? (Or some other way to achieve this?)

Comment: Why not just *use* EJS for this? Create two CSS files, one for each condition, and use EJS to render either stylesheet A or stylesheet B.

Comment: Use CSS variables in an EJS conditional maybe? It depends on what you need to change really